# How can I push my own numeric data to prometheus database?

Tags: database, time-series, prometheus

I know that prometheus is used for system monitoring, but I want to store some my own data into it. is it possible to store my numeric data? if possible how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus works in pull mode, so you will need to expose your numeric data as a metric for Prometheus to scrape.

have you tried using Gauges? https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/

**Gauge** : A gauge is a metric that represents a single numerical value that can arbitrarily go up and down.

Gauges are typically used for measured values like temperatures or current memory usage, but also "counts" that can go up and down, like the number of running goroutines.